# Javascript delete loop

Tags: javascript

I have a school assignment and I have an issue with deleting something from an array of indexes.
This is what I currently have.

Function that returns array length:

```
function DolzinaPolja(polje){   
    return polje.length-1;
}
```

new constructor

```
function oseba(ime, priimek, stranka) {
    this.ime=ime;
    this.priimek=priimek;
    this.stranka=stranka;
}
```

function that creates an object and pushes it into an array

```
function UstvariObjekt(ime,priimek, stranka) {
    if (ime.length == 0 || priimek.length == 0 || stranka.length == 0) {
        throw "Parametri niso popolni!";
    }
    else {
        var novaoseba=new oseba(ime, priimek, stranka);
        polje.push(novaoseba);
        console.log(novaoseba.ime, novaoseba.priimek, novaoseba.stranka);
    }
}
```

function that deletes an object from the array

```
function OdstraniIzPolja(x) {
    if(x > polje.length - 1 || x == polje.length) {
        throw"Polje ni tako veliko!";
    }
    for(var i=0; i<=polje.length-1;i++) {
        if(x==polje[i]) {
            polje.splice(x,1);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am having an issue with deleting an object from the array.
Here are my tests.

```
var polje = [];
var x=0;

UstvariObjekt("Rene","Vucko","Stranka");
UstvariObjekt("R","V","S");
UstvariObjekt("X","Y","Z");

OdstraniIzPolja(x);
console.log(polje[0]);
console.log(polje[1]);
console.log(polje[2]);
console.log(DolzinaPolja(polje));
```

SO my array should be the length of 2. Since I start with 0,1,2. What I don't understand is why doesn't my function that deletes an object from the array delete the object? I've played around a little bit but often it just deletes the wrong object.

Also is the if clause for x if the length is smaller than the array length written ok?

---UPDATE----
IF I write 
polje.slice(2,1) without the function just in the program, it deletes the right one. So obviously something is wrong with the loop.
This is my updated code.

```
function DolzinaPolja(polje){   
    return polje.length-=1;
}

function OdstraniIzPolja(x)
{
    if(x>polje.length-1 || x==polje.length)
    {
        throw"Polje ni tako veliko!";
    }
    for(var i=polje.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(x==polje[i]){
        polje.splice(i,1);
        return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

--EDIT--
here's the code https://jsfiddle.net/2y07wtkL/

Comment: DolzinaPolja is not returning the length, it's returning the length minus one.

Comment: In your `OdstraniIzPolja` function, since `x` is an index and you're checking to see if it's in the proper range... you shouldn't need the loop at all, right?

Comment: What is the console log output?

Comment: ene Vucko Stranka
funkcije.js:32 R V S
funkcije.js:32 X Y Z
uporaba.js:17 Rene R X
uporaba.js:19 oseba {ime: "Rene", priimek: "Vucko", stranka: "Stranka"}
uporaba.js:20 oseba {ime: "R", priimek: "V", stranka: "S"}
uporaba.js:21 undefined
uporaba.js:22 1

Comment: and here are the calls

UstvariObjekt("Rene","Vucko","Stranka");
UstvariObjekt("R","V","S");
UstvariObjekt("X","Y","Z");
console.log(polje[0].ime, polje[1].ime, polje[2].ime);
OdstraniIzPolja(x);
console.log(polje[0]);
console.log(polje[1]);
console.log(polje[2]);
console.log(DolzinaPolja(polje));

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2y07wtkL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you splice the object with wrong index.
If you splice using

```
polje.splice(x,1);
```

you remove the element at x index. That means when you remove first element from array, the second element from array becomes first, so the next iteration won't delete the second element you want to be deleted, but the second element from array will be deleted instead (it doesn't have to be the element you are currently iterating on).

Comment: To build on this.. it looks like you want to be doing `polje.splice(i, 1);`  since you first checked that the value of index i is equal to x.

Comment: I tried switching x with i but nothing gets deleted :/

Comment: If you want to remove just one entry from array, use pojle.splice(pojle.indexOf(x, 1)) and don't make any loop.

Comment: @P0lip you have a small typo in your splice function. Change it to pojle.splice(pojle.indexOf(x), 1) and you are correct.

Comment: I don't get it. If I write
polje.splice(polje.indexOf(x), 1);
and I set x to 1, it deletes the last element, so the one on the index 2, and if I set the x to 0, it still deletes the one on the index 2.

Comment: Was a typo. pojle.splice(pojle.indexOf(x), 1) is correct.
@ReneDrugiacc
Could you post the new code? On JSFiddle for instance?

Comment: Forget to point it. You should pass the thing you want to delete, not the index. So in your case it's redundant.
I've updated your code to reflect it.
https://jsfiddle.net/2y07wtkL/1/
I only removed indexOf and just put x instead. Check it out!

Comment: But how do I implment this function then?
https://jsfiddle.net/d97wzx22/

I want it to write out only 1 index name and surname

Comment: Okay this is the last function I need for this project. So for instance an user enters a variable. Lets say this variable is y="Rene";
so now I would need to iterate through the array and check if any string matches y, and write out the WHOLE OBJECT, so also priimek and stranka. If none match, it returns null.

Comment: Nevrmind it works, just did this:

function IsciPoImenu(y){
 for(var i=polje.length-1;i>=0;i--)
 {
  if(y==polje[i].ime)
  {
   console.log(polje[i].ime, polje[i].priimek, polje[i].stranka)
  }
  
 }
 
  return null;
 

}

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function DolzinaPolja(polje){   
    return polje.length -= 1;
}
```

as in your solution you just subtract the lenght, but you dont asign it

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are deleting from a collection with indices you should do it from the end so that you are indices don't change after each delete. I think that's what is happening. Change the direction like this

```
for(var i=polje.length-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    ........
}
```